# How to reduce the size of ipa file

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to reduce the size of an `IPA` file.

I have reduced the resources ,but I don‘t know how to reduce the Executable file in the `IPA`.

Is there some archive setting that can reduce the Executable file size?

Comment: Hey, you have provided no information about your project here. The more info you provide the more we can try to help. What size is your current file? What sort of content is in the project? (Videos, images, etc...) what type of app is it? Is it a game? Is it a todo list? How big is the project? How many lines of code etc... what language are you using to write the app? Etc... any information you can provide will help us help you.

Comment: Did you get hint with this article ? [Reducing the size of my App -  developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1795/_index.html)

Comment: Why do you need to reduce the IPA size? How big is it?

Comment: Thank you guys! Our boss said our download ipa is too bigger. Now our ipa's size is 74mb(3x retina).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is app thinning.

You have made the right start with looking at the resources files and reducing the size of them. You could go a step further though and use on demand resources to reduce the impact of the resources folder even further.

You should check through your code as well and ensure that you do not have any files included that are not used.

Another thing is to ensure that you do not have any data stored in the code as this is inefficient because the data in code cannot be compressed and will instead be compiled.

Also optimise your code to ensure that you do not have lines of code that are not required.

You can also set the optimization level in the compiler settings in xCode. You should set them to `Smallest [-Os]`.

There is an official guide to app thinning on the Apple Developer site:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1795/_index.html

You can also find a number of additional resources on app thinning on various tutorial and blog sites.

Comment: Thank you ! I have read the document of guide to app thinning on the Apple Developer site , I will reduce the ipa size by two steps. At the first step I reduce the resource ,our release build configure is all configure as the advices . At the second step ,I will reduce the executable file by code review .